Find three finite dimensional semisimple $\mathbb{R}$ algebras
I'm asked to find three finite dimensional semisimple $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, $R$, each with only one simple module $S$ up to isomorphism so $R\simeq S\oplus S$ as $R$-modules. I'm guessing I need to use Artin-Wedderburn. If we let $R$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ algebra then by Artin-Wedderburn, we know that $R\simeq M_{n_1}(D_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus M_{n_s}(D_s)$, where $D_i$ are finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ division algebras. Moreover, in this decomposition there are precisely $s$ simple modules up to isomorphism. Using this, it's easy to see that if $R$ is a candidate having the required properties then, that $R\simeq M_n(D)$ where $D$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ division algebra. By Frobenius theorem, there are only $3$ finite dimension $\mathbb{R}$ division algebras, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$. My problem is in determining which of these satisfy the condition that $R\simeq S\oplus S$, where $S$ is the sole simple $R$-module up to isomorphism.
It certainly can't be that $n=1$ and $D=\mathbb{R}$. But beyond this, I am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

For a division ring $D$, $M_n(D)$ has composition length 2 iff $n=2$.  One can see this by observing that the subset of matrices which is nonzero only on row $i$ is a simple right ideal.
So you're looking for three finite dimensional $\mathbb R$-division algebras, each of which you use for $D$ in $M_2(D)$.  You already mentioned three such algebras...

Note that $\dim(R) = n^2 \cdot \dim(D)$ while $\dim(S \oplus S) = 2 \dim(S) = 2n \cdot \dim(D)$, so necessarily $n = 2$.
